# Camel-jms create connection to EMS / IBMMQ via servicemix Karaf

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

What I'm trying to do is making a connection to EMS and IBM MQ. So I've tried to get some knowledge from camel.apache.org and people.apache.org about camel-jms component and try to make a connection to those like from ActiveMQ component. I run the application in the docker so instead of localhost I used host.docker.internal and it's working fine for me.

```xml
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.camel.component.activemq.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://host.docker.internal:61616"/>
    <property name="username" value="admin"/>
    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>
...
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring>
    <route id="input">
      <from uri="activemq:INPUT-QUEUE"/>
      <!-- Process message -->
      <to uri="activemq:OUTPUT-QUEUE"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is making the same thing for those 2 that I'm already mentioned.

```xml
<bean id="ibmMqTryout" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
</bean>
```

I do not know what kind of field I need to use and what I've tried is to reference some JMSConfiguration and JMSConnectionFactory Bean, but I don't get how it works in servicemix. Additionally I would like to use some Environment Properties for EMS connection.
I know this question is really chaotic, but I'm in dead end right now.

Comment: If you have a different JMS Provider/Implementation you want to talk with just replace the component in your route. For IBM MQ and EMS (I don't know this implementation by the way) just use the generic [JMS component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/jms-component.html) so it fits all.

Comment: http://www.masterspringboot.com/camel/integration-with-ibm-mq-made-simple-with-camel/ IBM MQ is part of JMS but some fields of it is special for IBM MQ. Should use its client.